# Rails -Namespace Css Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a admin namespace into my web application .**It is working fine on my local machine** but when I am trying to deploy the application none of my css is working.
I tried

> rake assets:precompile

I have restarted the server .My structure looks like this

- app

  - assets

    - stylesheets

      . application.css

      - admin

        - my_admin.css

The same structure is with Javascripts.In my layout file I have used

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin/my_admin" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "admin/my_admin" %>
```

When I run  my application it works fine but none of my css nor javascript is there ..In my Browser inspector it is saying my_admin css and javascript not found.Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production you likely have

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

in your `config/environment/production.rb`. This prevents the asset pipeline from compiling scripts on demand in production as it does in development.

You need to specify any `.js` or `.css` assets you want precompiled which are not `application.js` or `application.css`.

Adding the following to your `config/environment/production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += ["admin/my_admin.css", "admin/my_admin.js"]
```

and running `rake assets:precompile` should put those compiled assets into `public/assets` for you.

Comment: This worked by putting the following configuration into my application.rb .Thanks